# Here I have used functions and arrays to find out whether the matrix is symmetric or non- symmetric . Can anyone optimise my code using pointers?

Tags: c, function, pointers, matrix, multidimensional-array

Here we are given a martix and we have to find out whether the matrix is symmetrix or not. I want to optimise it using array pointer or passsing by reference or you can suggest better approach , which uses multiple concepts, and please provide an explanation , it would be helpful.
I am learning arrays so, that why I am asking you to use multiple concepts , I want to see if there is a better approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int arr[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = arr[i][j];
    arr[i][j] = arr[j][i];
    arr[j][i] = temp;
}

void check(int arr[3][3], int i, int j)
{
    static int count = 0;

    if (arr[i][j] == arr[j][i])
    {
           count++;
        if (count == 9)
        {
            printf("matrix is symmetric");
        }
    }
}
int main()
{

    int arr[3][3] = {1, 3, 3,
                     3, 1, 5,
                     3, 5, 5};

    int i, j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++)
        {
            swap(arr, i, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("THE TRANSPOSE MATRIX IS \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            check(arr, i, j);
            if (arr[i][j] != arr[j][i])
            {
                printf("matrix is non-symmetric");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointers will make little/no difference in this, in no small part because, whether you realize it or not, you're already using them.  The structure of the program itself, and particularly that `static count` logic, on the other hand... consider cleaning that up just because of how hideous it is. Regardless, if the code works, this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com for input; not here.

Answer (score 0):

To find symmetric matrix simply use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define dim 4

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int arr[dim][dim]= {1, 3, 2, 3,
                        3, 1, 5, 4,
                        2, 5, 5, 16,
                        3, 4, 16, 7};

    int isSymmetric = 1;
    while (isSymmetric && i<dim)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < dim; j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j]!=arr[j][i]) {
                isSymmetric = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    isSymmetric==1?printf("Symmetric"):printf("notSymmetric");
    return 0;
}
```

The complexity of this algorithm at most is **O(N/2)** when **N** is the number of elements.